# Custom function to compute mean absolute deviation

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a 4D numpy array similar to this:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>from functools import partial

>>>X = np.random.rand(20, 1, 10, 4)

>>>X.shape
(20, 1, 10, 4)
```

I calculate the following statistics `mean, median, std, p25, p75`

```
>>>percentiles = tuple(partial(np.percentile, q=q) for q in (25,75))
>>>stat_functions = (np.mean, np.std, np.median) + percentiles

>>>stats = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in stat_functions], axis=2)
```

So that:

```
>>>stats.shape
(20, 1, 5, 4)

>>>stats[0]
array([[[0.55187202, 0.55892688, 0.45816177, 0.6378181 ],
        [0.31028278, 0.32109677, 0.17319351, 0.13341651],
        [0.57112019, 0.60587194, 0.45490572, 0.59787335],
        [0.30857011, 0.30367621, 0.28899686, 0.55742753],
        [0.80678815, 0.82014851, 0.61295181, 0.70529412]]])
```

I am interested in `mad` among the statistics, so I define this function since it is not available with numpy.

```
def mad(data):
    mean = np.mean(data)
    f = lambda x: abs(x - mean)
    vf = np.vectorize(f)
    return (np.add.reduce(vf(data))) / len(data)
```

But I am having issues getting this function work: First I tried:

```
>>>stat_functions = (np.mean, np.std, np.median, mad) + percentiles
>>>stats = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in stat_functions], axis=2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-33-fa6d972f0fce> in <module>()
----> 1 stats = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in stat_functions], axis=2)

<ipython-input-33-fa6d972f0fce> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 stats = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in stat_functions], axis=2)

TypeError: mad() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

I then modify the definition of `mad` to:

```
def mad(data, axis=None):
    ...
```

Got into this issue:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-c74d9e3d057b> in <module>()
----> 1 stats = np.concatenate([f(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for f in my_func], axis=2)

<ipython-input-35-c74d9e3d057b> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 stats = np.concatenate([f(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for f in my_func], axis=2)

TypeError: mad() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keepdims'
```

So also doing:

```
def mad(data, axis=None, keepdims=None):
    ...
```

Got me into:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c74d9e3d057b> in <module>()
----> 1 stats = np.concatenate([f(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for f in my_func], axis=2)

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 4 dimension(s) and the array at index 3 has 3 dimension(s)
```

I know this has to do with the dimensionality issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it work in this case.

***EDIT:**

Based on the answer given, I got a strange result after using the `mad` function of the answer, like this:

```
stat_functions = (np.mean, np.std, np.median,mad) + percentiles

stats = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in stat_functions], axis=2)

stats.shape
(20, 1, 15, 4)
```

The expected output should have the shape `(20,1,6,4)` since I'm adding one value of statistic to in the third dimension: `(np.mean, np.std, np.median, mad) + percentiles`

**EDIT-2**

Using this function from the answer:

```
def mad(data, axis=-1, keepdims=True):
    return np.abs(data - data.mean(axis, keepdims=True)).mean(axis)
```

And then:

```
stat_functions = (np.mean, np.std, np.median, mad) + percentiles

stats = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in stat_functions], axis=2)
```

Then run into this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-fa6d972f0fce> in <module>()
----> 1 stats = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in stat_functions], axis=2)

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 4 dimension(s) and the array at index 3 has 3 dimension(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice with your code `vf` is by no means a vectorize function (see the note in [Numpy's doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). You can just use `np.abs` instead of `abs` and your function will be vectorized.

That said, your function can be written as:

```
def mad(data):
    return np.abs(data - data.mean(0))/ len(data)
```

Now, note that this `mad` function, or your original function, only accepts **one** positional parameter and **no** optional parameter. The error you got is because you are trying to pass `axis=2` to `mad`:

```
[func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in stat_functions]
```

To fix this issue, build the function with an optional parameter:

```
def mad(data, axis=-1, keepdims=True):
    return np.abs(data - data.mean(axis, keepdims=keepdims)).sum(axis)/len(data)
```

Or it might make more sense to use `mean(axis)` than `sum(axis)/len(data)`

```
def mad(data, axis=-1, keepdims=True):
    return np.abs(data - data.mean(axis, keepdims=True)).mean(axis)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I expect the 3rd dimension of `stats` to increase by one from `(20,1,5,4)` to `(20,1,6,4)` since I'm adding the value of one statistic `mad` but `stats.shape` is now `(20,1,15,4)` stange!

Comment: And the function doesn't look like it returns `ABSOLUTE`  value!!!

Comment: @arilwan see update with added `np.abs` and `sum(axis)`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I then get another error with `keepdims` parameter. `TypeError: mad() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keepdims'`

Comment: This happen when I add the `mad` to my statistics function: `stat_functions = (np.mean, np.std, np.median, mad) + percentiles`

Comment: You don't really need `keepdims` for `mad`, but similar to `axis`, you can modify `mad` with additional `keepdims` argument. See updates.

Comment: I understand I must be struggling with dimensionality. With the recent update to the function in your answer, run into another issue as in the question edit.